# In Mexico, where can I buy prepaid credit cards?

Tags: payment-cards, mexico

Next week, I will be in Mexico and I have only a VISA debit card. Are there any prepaid cards that I can get in Mexico to use for online transactions while I'm there?

Comment: Are you able to use your VISA debit online where you are currently? And, are you going to be in Mexico for a length of time, where you'd open an account at a bank there?

Comment: Good question. Transferwise offers prepaid cards in many currencies including pesos. I haven't tried it yet.